# Pure virtual function call error

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I get persistently an error which says "pure virtual function call".
After some research I found out that such error usually occurs when pure virtual method is called from constructor or destructor of an abstract base class.
However, this is not issue with my code, and after spending few hours trying to find solution I realised I need help :)

This is base class:

```
class Radnik {

string ime;
double procenat;

Radnik(const Radnik& r) = delete;
Radnik& operator = (const Radnik& r) = delete;

public:

Radnik(string i, double p) : ime(i), procenat(p) {}
virtual ~Radnik() {}

virtual double prihod() = 0;
```

**4)...and finally here where it calls function prihod() for abstract base class**

```
double plata() { return prihod()*procenat / 100; }
```

**3)... and here ˇˇ**

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& it, Radnik& r) { return it << r.ime << " / " << r.plata()<<endl; }


};
```

Prodavac and Sef are derived classes.

This is another class used in program:

```
class Firma {
int rm;
double marza;
Radnik** niz;

public:

Firma(int radna_mesta, double m) : rm(radna_mesta), marza(m) { niz = 
 new Radnik*[rm];  for (int i = 0; i < rm; niz[i++] = nullptr){} }
~Firma() { delete[] niz; }

Firma& operator += (Radnik& r) { for (int i = 0; i < rm; i++)
{if (niz[i] == nullptr) { niz[i] = &r; return *this; } } throw G_fpun(); }
Firma& operator -= (int i) { if (i < 0 || i >= rm) throw G_findeks(); 
if(niz[i + 1] == nullptr) throw G_fbezrad(); niz[i + 1] = nullptr; 
return  *this; }

double dobit() { double prihod(0), plate(0); for (int i = 0; i < rm; i++)
{ prihod += niz[i]->prihod(); plate += niz[i]->plata(); } 
return  prihod*marza / 100 - plate; }
```

**2) ... and from there it jumps here ˇ**

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& it, Firma& f) 
{ for (int i = 0; i < f.rm; i++) 
 { it << "Radnik broj " << i + 1 << " ( " <<    *f.niz[i] << " )" << endl;         
return it << f.dobit(); } }

 };
```

And this is main program:

```
cout << "Koliko radnika ima firma i koja joj je marza (u procentima) ?"; 
int n; double m; cin >> n >> m;
Firma f(n, m);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

cout << "\nDa li je radnik broj " << i + 1 << "prodavac (p) ili sef (s) ?"; 

char izb; cin >> izb;

if (izb == 'p' || izb == 'P') { cout << "\nIme, procenat zarade od prihoda i  
prihodi prodavca ?\n"; string im; double pro, pri; cin >> im >> pro >> pri;  
Prodavac p1(im, pro, pri); f += p1; }

if (izb == 's' || izb == 'S') {
cout << "Ime, procenat zarade od prihoda i broj podredjenih ?";
string im; double pro; int brp; cin >> im >> pro >> brp;


if (i + brp>=n) throw G_fpun();

Sef sf(im, pro, brp); f += sf;

for (int j = 0; j < brp; j++){ cout << "\nIme, procenat zarade od prihoda i  
prihodi prodavca ?\n"; 
string ii; double proo; double prii; cin >> ii >> 
proo >> prii; Prodavac p2(ii, proo, prii); f += p2; i++; }

                              }

}
cout << f;
```

**1) the problem starts here ^ at the end of program when I try to call overloaded operator <<**

I tried to help you out to orientate in this code, thank you in advance for any help, I've been stuck here for the whole day.

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read because of poor formatting.

Comment: Where do you actually provide definitions of the prihod() member function?

Comment: Agreed with rici, the prihod method is made abstract I guess one of the derived classes does not implement it. You even use Radnik itself, which has an abstract method... And as you use C++1x elements (= delete, nullptr etc), why not go all the way and replace the **, new and delete stuff by smart pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating temporaries in your code, then passing them to your `+=` operator which keeps a pointer to those temporaries which then get destroyed:

```
Prodavac p1(im, pro, pri); f += p1;
```

This results in Undefined Behavior when you access the (now invalid) references stored in `Firma`.  In this specific case, since the referenced objects have been destroyed, the vtable has been rolled back to the base class (with the pure virtual function in it), which results in your error.